# Suppress captive network portal

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm working on an Android hotel app that will connect a user to the hotels wifi hotspot, if they have the app installed.

I've registered a receiver in the app manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Everything is working fine with the authentication of the hotspot, but the OS launches a browser for the captive portal page. Is there a way for my app to tell Android to suppress this behaviour for specific SSIDs - that is, register this app as the 'hotspot authentication handler'.

The behaviour I'm looking for is the same as CNSetSupportedSSIDs from the iOS Captive Network framework.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do this, since captive portal support is not a well supported API in android SDK.

If it is not standard API, that means different vendor might have different way to do this detection and login